# How to initialise a list inside a loop and then append?

Tags: python, list, loops

It is possible to initialise a list inside a loop, and append objects to the list in the same loop, without always clearing the list when initalising it?

```
for j in range(5):    
  mylist=[]
  mylist.append(j)
```

The result would be a list with one element, but of course I want a list with 5 elements. Is there a nice way to do that?

I'm asking because I need to initialise a list in a function and use this function several times, without clearing the list each time I use the function, but appending the new object. You understand what I mean? At the moment I'm using something like this:

```
if first == True:
  mylist = []
  first = False

mylist.append("bla")
```

but it doesn't looks nice.
Thanks in advance and sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 7):

You can define your function to receive a *default argument*:

```
def f(element, L = []):
    L.append(element)
    print L       # you can also use 'return L'

# test
for i in range(5):
    f(i)
```

**Output:**

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

This will work because the [default arguments are evaluated **only once**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just initialize the list before the loop/function?

```
save_elem_internal_list = []
def save_elem(elem):
    save_elem_internal_list.append(elem)
```

If you want to avoid the global variable, you can store the data in the function itself:

```
def save_elem(elem):
    if not hasattr(elem, 'store'):
        elem.store = []
    elem.store.append(elem)
```

Both of these solutions more obvious than the list-default-argument version by Christian, which is a bit too subtle for my taste. In my experience, that just leads to headache later on.